# Windows 7 boot manager

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, hyper-v

I have Windows 7 installed as my main operating system on my machine and recently installed Hyper V Server on a separate hard disk.  Now I have realised that I don't use Hyper V as much as I thought I might and want to remove it from the machine completely.

The only thing holding me back from completely formatting that disk is the boot manager. When I try to boot from the disk with Windows 7 installed on it, I get an error telling me the boot manager can't be found.  However when the machine boots from the disk with Hyper V Server on it, the boot manager loads fine.

Basically what I want to know is, if I remove the Hyper V Server and my computer begins just trying to boot the Windows 7 disk automatically, will I continue to get this error of not being able to find the boot manager?  If so, what steps will I need to take prior to the Hyper V uninstallation in order to be able to boot correctly into Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Install EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)

Run it from within Windows 7. With this program you can edit your bootloader with a GUI (which I prefer over a command line).

You can add and delete installations, so delete your Hyper-V entry and after that you can savely delete the partition. Problem solved!

[image]

Just a note of caution: you can seriously screw up your computer if you don't know what you're doing here. Either make a backup (which I think is an option as well) or leave it be.

Comment: BTW the note isn't aimed at jmitch18 ;-) Anyone with Hyper-V on his computer most likely isn't a complete beginner

Comment: This sounds like a nice solution.  I will give it a go once I get home from work.  Computer backups are already made online via Live Mesh, so even if I do mess it up, I can simply resinstall Windows 7 and sync with Mesh.  I just don't want to do the Visual Studio install yet again :(

Comment: Note that you have to use this in Windows 7 (probably) to make sure it creates the boot files on that partition. Besides worst case scenario: use Windows's backup function and backup the entire installation. Nothing will be lost that way.

Comment: Is EasyBCD available for Windows 7?

Comment: @alex I couldn't imagine why not. Unless the program explicitly checks the OS then there shouldn't be any compatibility issues if it runs in Vista.

Comment: @alex: points at the image (it says Windows 7 Beta 1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) related to this on the Microsoft Help and Support page:

> To run the Bootrec.exe tool, you must
>   start Windows RE. To do this, follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive,
>      and then start the computer.
> 2. Press a key when you are prompted.
> 3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input
>      method, and then click Next.
> 4. Click Repair your computer.
> 5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click
>      Next.
> 6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
> 7. Type Bootrec.exe, and then press ENTER.

There's more info on the page, including the flags that bootrec takes.